# Create video from bunch of JPEGs

Tags: ffmpeg, jpeg

I have a CCTV camera that uploads JPEG images (.jpg) to an FTP server when it detects movement. We seem to get quite a few images, so I would like to make them into a video to ease viewing.

I've done several Google searches, but nothing quite produces what I expect to see. The folder I am using has over 2000 images which are named AyyMMddhhmmssff.jpg. If I need to rename, I can do that since I already find I need to for FFMPEG to work.

I'd like an image per second, or maybe 2 per second so the images are easy to view when playing the video back. Yes, I know that will result in a 20/40min+ video!

I'm happy with a Windows, macOS or Ubuntu solution! My preference would be Windows (since that is where the FTP server is).

**ImageMagick**

```
convert *.jpg video.mpg
```

This sounded great, nice and simple. However, I have tried on my Mac (installed via brew) and Ubuntu and both grind performance of the relative system to a halt and after 20 minutes, still not finished. I had to reboot the Mac as I couldn't do anything!

**FFMPEG**

```
ffmpeg -y -r 6 -f image2 -s 1920x1080 -i <path>\%06d.jpg -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p <path>/video.mp4
```

I'm no expert when it comes to using FFMPEG, but I have used it for several tasks and found it to be a great utility to have around. The above command does produce a video, but the images display too quickly removing the point of the video. I tried tweaking the values and can get it better, but not exactly what I am after. One attempt (setting `-r 1` IIRC) resulted in a single image for the entire video! Its clear I don't understand the various arguments in the FFMPEG command even though I have looked at the manual!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you rename the images to be consecutively numbered, then you can use

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 1 -i <path>\%06d.jpg -r 5 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p <path>/video.mp4
```

Consecutively numbered, as in `000001.jpg`,`000002.jpg`,`000003.jpg`... Note that there are exactly 6 characters in each name, which satisfies the `%06d` passed on to ffmpeg.

If you don't want to rename, then create a text file of the form,

```
file first.jpg
file second.jpg
file third.jpg
...
file last.jpg
```

and then

```
ffmpeg -f concat -r 1 -i list.txt -r 5 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p <path>/video.mp4
```

Comment: I have already been renaming the images in the format "yyyyMMdd_000001.jpg" etc. but when I run your command, I get the same result I have seen previously with FFMPEG of a single image throughout the video (41mins). Would the name be causing this or something else?!

Comment: Add `-report` to your execution and paste or link to he report in your Q.

Comment: With that number of images the log was too long to post to pastebin, so I reduced the number of images processed, same result: https://pastebin.com/03CTErCu

Comment: The log shows no errors; it is as expected. Can you share the output?

Comment: You mean the actual video?

Comment: Yes.  That's the nest way to check.

Comment: OK, so I uploaded it, however when I viewed it, it was working! Tried from the file on my local HDD and still just showed a single image. Tried another player and it worked! So it appears to be an issue with VLC, would never have thought VLC would have an issue!

Comment: There was a long standing bug with low framerates in VLC. Fixed a few months back.

Comment: Latest version of VLC does indeed sort the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

instead of the -r 5, change it to -framerate 5
That will produce a video with 5 frames per second. You can adjust that number to suit your needs, 1 would show each image for 1 second, 10 would cycle through more quickly..

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 1 -i <path>\%06d.jpg -framerate 5 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p <path>/video.mp4

or

ffmpeg -f concat -r 1 -i list.txt -framerate 5 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p <path>/video.mp4
```