# ffmpeg only showing one frame in timelapse

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, slideshow, timelapse

I run `ffmpeg -start_number 1561703179 -i asl-0136/screenshot-%10d.png -vframes 16 -pix_fmt yuv444p -r 1 hi.mp4`
, but the output video only contains one frame, even though I have 64 in the directory.

Maybe related to [FFMPEG slideshow from images - only one frame shown](https://superuser.com/questions/714079/ffmpeg-slideshow-from-images-only-one-frame-shown), but I'm on Arch with a different version

I also don't want to use globbing because I need Windows support

Output of `ls` of the folder:

```
screenshot-1561703162.png  screenshot-1561703375.png  screenshot-1561703588.png  screenshot-1561703801.png  screenshot-1561704014.png
screenshot-1561703179.png  screenshot-1561703392.png  screenshot-1561703605.png  screenshot-1561703818.png  screenshot-1561704030.png
screenshot-1561703195.png  screenshot-1561703408.png  screenshot-1561703621.png  screenshot-1561703835.png  screenshot-1561704047.png
screenshot-1561703211.png  screenshot-1561703425.png  screenshot-1561703638.png  screenshot-1561703851.png  screenshot-1561704063.png
screenshot-1561703227.png  screenshot-1561703441.png  screenshot-1561703654.png  screenshot-1561703867.png  screenshot-1561704080.png
screenshot-1561703243.png  screenshot-1561703458.png  screenshot-1561703671.png  screenshot-1561703883.png  screenshot-1561704096.png
screenshot-1561703260.png  screenshot-1561703474.png  screenshot-1561703687.png  screenshot-1561703899.png  screenshot-1561704112.png
screenshot-1561703276.png  screenshot-1561703490.png  screenshot-1561703704.png  screenshot-1561703916.png  screenshot-1561704129.png
screenshot-1561703293.png  screenshot-1561703506.png  screenshot-1561703720.png  screenshot-1561703932.png  screenshot-1561704145.png
screenshot-1561703309.png  screenshot-1561703523.png  screenshot-1561703736.png  screenshot-1561703948.png  screenshot-1561704161.png
screenshot-1561703326.png  screenshot-1561703539.png  screenshot-1561703752.png  screenshot-1561703965.png  screenshot-1561704177.png
screenshot-1561703342.png  screenshot-1561703555.png  screenshot-1561703769.png  screenshot-1561703981.png
screenshot-1561703359.png  screenshot-1561703572.png  screenshot-1561703785.png  screenshot-1561703997.png
```

version:

```
ffmpeg version n4.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-
-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --e
ibidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libmodplug --enable-libm
encore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libsoxr --enabl
enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enab
able-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-shared --en
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
```

Comment: Are the images consecutively numbered?

Comment: @Gyan Edited question

Comment: The images need to be consecutively numbered. Use the concat demuxer instead. See https://superuser.com/a/1379084